# selecting an option from context menu using protractor

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

Tried several options but not able to select the option after opening context menu.

```
.step('Performing Undo Operation', page.paragraph1.click(), function(){     
    browser.actions().click(protractor.Button.RIGHT).sendKeys(protractor.Key.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER).perform().then(function() {
         console.log('Undo Done');
    })

    // Option 2               
    //browser.actions().click(protractor.Button.RIGHT).sendKeys(protractor.Key.chord("u",protractor.Key.ENTER)).perform();


    // Option 3
    // browser.actions().click(protractor.Button.RIGHT).perform();
    // browser.sleep(2000);
    //browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER).perform();  
})
```

Comment: what error are you getting? also how are you trying to access the menu is not clear in the question

Comment: @nullpointer he is doing a right click on the currently selected element (protractor.Button.RIGHT) and then using sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN) to select a menu item, and then using sendKeys(Keys.ENTER) to click it.

Comment: @anuj-chaudhary Some of my context menu's in my app lose focus after doing arrow_down once, if I do arrow_down twice it will correctly select the first menu item, from then on it works fine. Perhaps your context menu has the same bug?

Comment: @nullpointer , first of all thanks for your time. And secondly i am not receiving any error message as the operations which i would like to perform using keyboard keys such as ARROW_DOWN and ENTER are performed in the background screen instead of context menu.                            And i tried passing the ARROW_DOWN key twice key but still the same result action is performed on background screen.                                   NOTE: When the context menu is opened at the same time a tool tip is also active on the web page.

Comment: @Mobrockers Performing the ARROW_DOWN key operation twice also not able to resolve the problem